# compare top half matrix with bottom half

Tags: r, matrix

If I have the following data:

```
mat1           <- matrix( c(0,2,3,1,0,1,1,1,1), nrow=3 )
rownames(mat1) <- LETTERS[1:3]
colnames(mat1) <- LETTERS[1:3]

mat1
#  A B C
#A 0 1 1
#B 2 0 1
#C 3 1 1
```

how do get to a `data.frame` where I know which rowise matrix entries are bigger than the column entries? E.g. I would want for as a result for `mat1` is some sort of `data.frame` indicating:

```
A < B 
A < C 
B > A
B = C
C > A
C = B
```

I have been messing around with  `upper.tri` etc using subtractions but this is not helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare each element `mat1[i,j]` 
with the corresponding element on the other side of the diagonal `mat1[j,i]`,
you can use the transpose `t`.

```
r <- sign( mat1 - t(mat1) )
r
#   A  B  C
# A 0 -1 -1
# B 1  0  0
# C 1  0  0

paste( 
  colnames(r)[col(r)], 
  ifelse(r>0, ">", ifelse(r<0, "<", "=")), 
  rownames(r)[row(r)] 
)
# [1] "A = A" "A > B" "A > C" "B < A" "B = B" "B = C" "C < A" "C = B" "C = C"
```

Comment: Nice: Subject, of course, to the usual caveats about using "==" with numeric results. I would suggest this as the initial step if this were being applied to `double` rather than `integer` results: `sign(zapsmall(mat1 -t(mat1) ) )`